# Depth testing not working openGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a cube which i'm drawing on screen, i have activated the depth testing in order for it not to be transparent, the thing is, in the front and back side of the cube, it look's good.
but when translating and rotating the cube, the results are strange, here are some photos to demonstrate:

front:

[image: front]

sides:

[image: side]

This see through effect is not welcomed of course.

Here is some relevant code:

Indices & vertices:

```
const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}},
    {{1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0}},
    {{1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1}},
    {{-1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}}
};

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    // Front
    0, 1, 2
    ,2, 3, 0,
    // Back
    4, 6, 5,
    4, 7, 6,
    // Left
    2, 7, 3,
    7, 6, 2,
    // Right
    0, 4, 1,
    4, 1, 5,
    // Top
    6, 2, 1,
    1, 6, 5,
    // Bottom
    0, 3, 7,
    0, 7, 4,
};
```

Layer setup:

```
- (void)setupLayer {
    _eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;
    _eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER);
}
```

Depth buffer setup:

```
- (void)setupDepthBuffer {
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_depthRenderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _depthRenderBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
}
```

Rendering:

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    CC3GLMatrix *projection = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
    float h = 4.0f * self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width;
    [projection populateFromFrustumLeft:-2 andRight:2 andBottom:-h/2 andTop:h/2 andNear:4 andFar:10];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection.glMatrix);

    CC3GLMatrix *modelView = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
    [modelView populateFromTranslation:CC3VectorMake(sin(CACurrentMediaTime()), 0, -5)];
    _currentRotation += displayLink.duration * 90;
    [modelView rotateBy:CC3VectorMake(_currentRotation, _currentRotation, 0)];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);

    glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float)* 3));
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 7));


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _floorTexture);
    glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 0);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]),
                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

**EDIT:**

adding the texture mapping function:

```
- (GLuint)setupTexture:(NSString *)fileName {
    // 1
    CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

        // 2
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);


    GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width*height*4, sizeof(GLubyte));


    CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4,
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    // 3
    CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), spriteImage);

    CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

    // 4
    GLuint texName;
    glGenTextures(1, &texName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

    free(spriteData);  
    return texName;    
}
```

What am i doing wrong over here?

Comment: It's hard to gather from the screenshots what the problem is. Is the object transparent, or are the textures simply messed up ?

Comment: The texture is not supposed to be messed up, only the front face has a texture, and the others should just be white...

Comment: Sounds like your texture mapping is going wrong. Check your uv co-ordinates. Also make sure that 7 is the correct multiplier for (sizeof(float) * 7));

Comment: @CGRasterMouse, i updated the question with the relevant texture mapping... if you will be kind to have a look it will be great. i can't find my error...

Answer (score 0):

`glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER);` - at least replace this with `GL_LEQUAL`.

Comment: Why should i do that?

Comment: `glDepthFunc` defines how rendering pixel is compared to onscreen depth value to pass it. `GL_NEVER` means never pass, `GL_LEQUAL` - pass if current depth value is less or equal than onscreen depth (so primitives that are closer to camera will overdraw already rendered ones). But in your case it's strange that something is rendered while `glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER)` is set. By the way, your screenshot definetely shows incorrect depth testing. You can set depth func in `render:` method to be sure that it is set.

Comment: I have changed it to equal, and moved it to render, but still nothings changing... i don't know where else to look :|

Comment: @Itzik984 it is LEQUAL the L is important

Comment: @ratchetfreak yeah its what i have... just a typo over here

Comment: Itzik984, could you run your code with `XCode OpenGL profiler` (you need iOS Device for that)? It will show you every rendering step with active OpenGL states.